# Given function $f$ find directional derivative of $\lVert \nabla f \rVert$ in direction given by $\nabla f$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, vector-analysis, laplacian, image-processing

Suppose we have a function $f(x,y)$ differentiable as many times as you like in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the gradient is given by

$$
\nabla f (x,y) = \left(f_x,f_y \right)^T
$$

cosine and sine of such vector are given by

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\cos \alpha = \frac{f_x}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert} \\
\sin \alpha = \frac{f_y}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert} \\
\end{array}
\right. ,
$$
I also define $u_\alpha = (\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha)^T$

I want to compute
$
\nabla_{\alpha} \left( \lVert \nabla f \rVert \right)
$
which should be given by
$$
\nabla_{\alpha} \left( \lVert \nabla f \rVert \right) = \langle \nabla \left( \lVert \nabla f \rVert \right) , u_{\alpha} \rangle = \frac{f_{xx} f_x}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert} \cdot \frac{f_x}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert} + \frac{f_{yy} f_y}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert} \cdot \frac{f_y}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert} = \\
\left(f_{xx} + f_{yy} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{f_x^2}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert^2} + \frac{f_y^2}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert^2} \right) = f_{xx} + f_{yy} = \nabla^2 f
$$

The question is: is this derivation of the Laplacian operator rigorous?

The reason of my question is given by the following quote, taken from a computer vision book (the topic is edge detection):

> For many applications, however, we wish to think such a continuous
>   gradient image to only return isolated edges, i.e., as single pixels
>   at discrete locations along the edge contours. This can be achieved by
>   looking for maxima in the edge strength (gradient magnitude) in a
>   direction perpendicular to the edge orientation, i.e., along the
>   gradient direction. Finding this maximum corresponds to taking a
>   directional derivative of the strength field in the direction of the
>   gradient and then looking for zero crossing. The desired directional
>   derivative is equivalent to the dot product between a second gradient
>   operator and the result of the first... The gradient dot product with
>   the gradient is called the Laplacian.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your computation of $\langle \nabla (\lVert \nabla f \rVert ), u_{\alpha} \rangle$?

Comment: I'm afraid it's wrong: The gradient of $|\nabla f|$ also contains mixed partials.

Comment: @Gibbs it's there already, I'll add an edit explaining why I'm doing this.

Comment: @user8469759 I did the same computation without getting your result. It would be good to see your steps.

Comment: @Gibbs The computation is wrong, as pointed out by Christian Blatter. For example $\partial_x \lVert \nabla f \rVert = \frac{f_{xx} + f_{xy}}{\lVert \nabla f \rVert}$, I forgot the mixed term. I'll should probably ask a different question why I can't get the result of the quote.

Comment: What is written in that book is quite in contradiction with what is written here: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~little/505/mynotes/2nd-directional-derivative.pdf